# Update Statement With Where Clause To Other Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have an update statement which needs to update two fields of a table but is dependent on its where clause which references other tables within the database.

For example.

```
UPDATE TABLE_ONE 
SET VALUE_ONE=1,VALUE_TWO=2 
WHERE TABLE_TWO.ID = 1818 AND TABLE_TWO.POSITION = TABLE_THREE.ID AND TABLE_ONE = TABLE_THREE.VALUE = TABLE_ONE.ID;
```

My question is how do I do this successfully. At the moment I get unknown column exception on the first parameter of the where clause.

I hope this is clear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Edited my question. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing table schema for your all tables but you can try to rewrite your update like this

```
UPDATE table_one t1 JOIN table_three t3
    ON t1.id = t3.value JOIN table_two t2
    ON t3.id = t2.position
   SET t1.value_one = 1, value_two = 2 
 WHERE t2.id = 1818
```